# using Context Api how to set initial state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, activation-context-api

I am fetching data from http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/todos receiving array using app level state how should i populate the initial state in Context API ?

```js
    const initialState={
        todos:[]
        ,
         current:null

    }

    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(Todoreducer, initialState)

    fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/todos')
    .then(data => data.json())
    .then(  res =>
        // console.log(res)
        state.todos= res
        )
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZEGX.png)
in this i am not getting state to other components but state is available in **TodoState** in React Tools

Comment: You should use dispatch to update state!!!!

Comment: Yeah I figure out earlier, BTW thank you !